# No audio when archiving for ad-hoc distribution?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I created a project that has more than 20MB audio files in the package but when I archive it and submit to ad-hoc testing no audios are play. When I test on my device I can hear the sound. Anything else I need to do for the ad-hoc distribution?

Comment: better clean the project and rebuild. also check wether the audio are present in your payload after build

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt many times. It is strange that one iPad can play the sound but the other iPad couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because another device has configured to disable the audio in control panel. Really annoying feature here but I am glad the issue is finally resolved.

Comment: How can other apps disable audio? Do you mean it lowered the volume to 0?

Comment: It's not other apps. It's the iOS built-in option in the slide-up control panel. It doesn't show the option by default though.

Comment: oops, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

No. There must be some other problem. There is nothing special about an ad hoc distribution in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is NO. For testing or reproducing same follow like this delete and clean your application from the device and re install(sync IPA) through ITunes. Surely there is some problem with your functionality/implementation not with apple distribution approach.